# I am a beginner in python where is the error

Tags: python

```py
#python
sql="UPDATE bebliothequee SET title=:titl,author=:autho,ISBN=:ISB WHERE oid='{}'.format(oid.get())",title='{}'.format(title_editor.get()),author='{}'.format(author_editor.get()),ISBN='{}'.format(ISBN_editor.get()),oid='{}'.format(record_id.get())
```

Comment: You know, it might be helpful to tell us where the error is

Comment: You seem to be at least missing a `"` after `oid='{}'`. Or perhaps you meant to move the `"` from after `oid.get())` back.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @quamrana  after where?

Comment: I don't know why you use `'{}'` - you should get the name result using directly `title_editor.get()` and other values - or using `str(...)` if you really have to convert it to string. As for me it should automatically convert to string without `str()` and `{}`

Comment: @furas  def update():
    connection=sqlite3.connect('bebliotheque.db')
    c=connection.cursor()
    record_id=id_box.get()
    sql="UPDATE bebliothequee SET title=:titl,author=:autho,ISBN=:ISB WHERE "oid='{}'.format(oid.get())",title='{}'.format(title_editor.get()),author='{}'.format(author_editor.get()),ISBN='{}'.format(ISBN_editor.get()),oid='{}'.format(record_id.get())
    c.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    editor.destroy()

Comment: I think you make one big mistake - it should be used in `execute()` like `execute("QUERY", (arg1, arg2)`

Comment: read my previous comment again - put error **IN QUESTION, not in comment** - it will be more readable and all people will see it - so more people may help you. People may not read comments.

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: I see one problem in code - you use `execute()` in wrong way - you run it as `execute(  (tuple_with_query_and_args) )` but you need `execute(query, (tuple_with_args))`. Assgning `sql = "query",agr1,arg2"` and later `execute(sql)` doesn't work as you expect

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is that you didn't read Stackoverflow documentation how to create good question. So you didn't add all details in question - and we can't read in your mind - and we can't help it.

Next mistake: you put code in comment but you should put it in question so it would be more readalbe but what is more important: all people could see it and help you.

---

Code shows that you try to create `sql =...` with all arguments for `execute()` and later use it in `execute()` but it doesn't work this way. You can't assing positional and named values to variable and later put it in function. You should use it directly in `execute()` or you should create list/tuple with positional variables and dictionary with named variables.

**BTW:** you don't need `'{}'.format()` to convert it to strings. You could use `str()` but I think `execute()` should convert it automatically.

```
query = "UPDATE bebliothequee SET title=:title, author=:author, ISBN=:ISBN WHERE oid=:oid"

execute(query, title=title_editor.get(), author=author_editor.get(), ISBN=ISBN_editor.get(), oid=record_id.get())
```

Other problem is that you use `:titl` but you should use full name `:title` like in argument `title=...`.

You have also `oid='{}'.format(oid.get()` inside query which is totally useless.

---

**BTW:** Eventually you can create `dictionary`

```
args = {
  'title': title_editor.get(), 
  'author', author_editor.get(), 
  'ISBN': ISBN_editor.get(), 
  'oid': record_id.get(),
}
```

and then you can use `**` to `unpack` it as `named arguments`

```
execute(query, **args)
```

Comment: thanks guys it  worked ✌️

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted and few minutes later you can upvote it.